# MvvmCross Specific ViewModel for MvxItemTemplate to populate AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: c#, android, autocomplete, xamarin, mvvmcross

I was wondering if, when you create a MvxListView in xml and use a MvxItemTemplate to describe the Items, there is a way to assign the ViewModel that gets used (assuming there is one) for each line.  I fixed a similar problem by extending my Item class, but I want to have another item be an AutoCompleteTextView that has its hint list populated from a database.  I can get the list into and IEnumerable, its just a matter of assign that list to to each item in the list.  I figure if I can control that creation of the ViewModel for each item, I can add a property that contains the hint list and bind it.

My main View is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ShipmentInventory.Items"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/inventoryitemview" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The view for the Item template is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <MvxSpinner
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource TagColors; SelectedItem TagColor"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/InputEditText"
        local:MvxBind="Text InventoryNumber" />
  <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/InputEditText"
        local:MvxBind="Text Articles; completionHint HintList" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I figure if I can control the ViewModel its using for each item, I can add a property to it called HintList.  Is there a way to do this?

Jim

Comment: AutoCompleteTextView coding can be tricky - you have to be careful with threading, you have to be careful to ensure each request gets a list, etc. There is an MvxAutoCompleteTextView helper, plus I know some people have recently used this - hopefully they'll be along with some helpful info...

Comment: Thanks @Stuart.  I will google up MvxAutoCompleteTextView.  I slept on it last night and I might just populate the list in my WCF class extension like I did the color list.  If it's static, it should only create one instance.

Comment: @Stuart, I saw that examples you suggested.  They all still seem to depend on you having access to the ViewModel for the data you are showing.  Is there a way to get or set the underlying ViewModel when data is displayed via MvxItemTemplate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out most of the nuances for this and created an example at

https://github.com/JimWilcox3/MvxAutoCompleteTest

In a nutshell, when you bind data to an MvxItemList, the object in the datamodel for each item acts as your ViewModel for that item.  In my example, I just created a list of items.  If you are working with data from say WCF, you can extend the object created in the WCF using a partial class.  In that partial class you can create MvxCommand and other things that you might want to bind to.  Hope this helps someone.